# How do I maintain reference the correct execution context for a click event in KnockoutJS?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, dom-events

Here is a jsFiddle which demonstrates my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/dDEd5/4/

In summary, I have a simple ViewModel:

```
ViewModel = function () {}
ViewModel.prototype = {
    child: function () {},
    children: new Array(3),

    outermethod: function () {
        this.innerMethod();
    },

    innerMethod: function () {
        alert("ok!");
    },

    outerProperty: function () {
        return this.innerProperty();
    },

    innerProperty: function() {
        return "Property is OK";
    }
}
```

I am attempting to bind this ViewModel using a 'click' binding. The problem is that when my binding uses the $parent context, the value of 'this' within my ViewModel fails to resolve to the ViewModel.

For example, this binding works fine:

```
<div>
    <span data-bind="text: outerProperty()"></span>
    <button data-bind="click: outermethod">This Works</button>
</div>
```

However, when I use another binding context and attempt to call my ViewModel using $parent, things break down. In the following two example, the property resolves fine; however, the buttons both error out:

```
<div>
    <!-- ko with: child -->
    <span data-bind="text: $parent.outerProperty()"></span>
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.outermethod">This Doesn't</button>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

and

```
<div>
    <!-- ko foreach: children -->
    <span data-bind="text: $parent.outerProperty()"></span> 
        <button data-bind="click: $parent.outermethod">These Don't Either</button>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

I have done my due diligence trying to understand how Execution Contexts work in javascript and why these examples fail; however, I am at at loss on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When Knockout executes a handler it uses the current data bound at that level as the context.  So, when using something like `$parent` or `$root`, this can cause issues.

There are a few ways to handle it:

-you can bind it to the proper context in the binding itself like:

```
`click: $parent.outermethod.bind($parent)`
```

This returns a new function that ensures `$parent` will be `this`.

-you can bind it in your view model. Since you are placing the function on the prototype it is a little more challenging.

One technique (not using prototype) is to use a variable to track the correct value of `this` and reference it in your function like:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  this.outermethod = function() {
     self.innerMethod();
  };

};
```

Using the prototype, you can still put the implementation on the prototype and then create a bound version on the actual instance like:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
   this.outermethod = this.outermethod.bind(this);
};
```

So, this will create a new function on the instance that call the prototype's implementation of the function with the correct context.